# Simultaneous diagonalization of commuting matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have 3 diagonalizable matrices $A,B,C$. They commute with each other $[A,B]=[B,C]=[A,C]=0$

[edit]
The matrix $A$ is Hermitian but $B$ and $C$ have no properties.
[/edit]

I can get the eigenvalues of $A$ : $a_{i\alpha_i}$. The index $i$ labels different eigenvalues. The index $\alpha_i$ lists all equal eigenvalue for a given $i$.

If an eigenvalue is degenerate $\alpha_i=\{1,2,\dots\}$, if it's unique $\alpha_i=1$.

If I'm not wrong, if the $i$th eigenvalue is not degenerate, the corresponding eigenvector is also an eigenvector of $B$ and $C$.

Now, let's say the $i$th eigenvalue is degenerate. I can have a basis of eigenvectors for this subspace $v_{i\alpha}$. With this eigenvectors I can create a matrix $M_{\alpha\beta} = v_{i\alpha}^T B v_{i\beta}$. By diagonalizing $B$, I can get the eigenvalues of the $B$ operator and then compute new eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ : $w_{i\beta} = \sum_{\alpha} m_{\beta}^{\alpha}v_{\alpha}$ where $m_{\beta}^{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$th component of the $\beta$th eigenvector of $M$.

At the end of this operation, I'm left with a set of eigenvectors that diagonalizes $A$ and $B$.

[edit]
I just realized that this new set is not orthogonal.
[/edit]

My main question comes now. I think I managed to find a correct set of eigenvectors because when I run a code that uses the method explained above, I get the correct result. But when I use the same procedure to diagonalize the third matrix, $C$, my code gives wrong result.

The matrices have been requested, so here they are (for this 12x12 matrix, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are symmetrical, but I'm looking for a solution that works for matrices with the above properties) :

A =

```
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

B=

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

C=

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: How large are your matrices? If they're relatively small, it'd be helpful to include them so that people can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Is $[A,B]=[B,A]=\cdots$ a typo? These are equal, of course, but do you know that $[B,C]=0$?

Comment: @cws it was a typo... thx

Comment: @Semiclassical they are quite small 10x10, do you think I should post them ?

Comment: That's not entirely small, but it still might be helpful.

Comment: @Semiclassical I updated my question with the matrices and some more info on there properties.

Comment: Did you note that B and C a priori don't have the same eigenvectors?

Comment: @PascalEngeler yes, but as they commute they can be diagonalized with the same set of eigenvectors... one just needs to find it, right?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @PinkFloyd yes. There is a set of eigenvectors which simultaneously diagonalizes a set of commuting matrices, given that they're all diagonalizable.

Comment: @user126154 I can't figure out what are my eigenvectors that diagonalizes my 3 matrices.

Comment: @user126154 I may have understood something, when I compute $C$, as my eigenvectors are no longer orthonormal, $M_{\alpha\beta} = v_{i\alpha}^TB v_{i\beta}$, I shouldn't use the transpose of the the eigenvectors but the left eigenvectors...